# JFileChooser не работает в одном эклипсе и работает в другом. код 1 в 1

Tags: java

Всем привет! Изучаю swing и встала проблема - не работает JFileChooser как надо. Думал проблема в коде. А потом... В общем, 2 скрина, один и тот же код - просто 1 кнопка на фрейме даже без Layout менеджера. Минимум кода для наглядности. Говорю сразу - код ОДИН И ТОТ ЖЕ. 
Кто-нибудь знает в чем может быть проблема? 
Внутренние библиотеки не трогал, давайте без ерунды. Обе версии эклипсов стоят отсилы 2 недели.

[image: Поведение в Luna EE edition]
[image: Поведение в Neon SE edition]

Comment: Блин, я думал что видно названия скринов. В общем, работает в Eclipse Luna EE. Не работает в Eclipse Neon SE.

Comment: Смотря на ошибки можно предположить, что проблема в том, что не хватает каких-то элементов в JDK (ну раз код одинаковый то?).
Раз проблема в java se, попробуйте поставить jdk se - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
Возможно у Вас стоит только ee jdk.